# Solve a linear equation system of convolutions

Tags: convolution

For linear systems of equations, like `Ax = b`, the solution that minimizes the mean squared error and the norm is given as `argmin((Ax-b)^2 = (A^T A + sigma*Identity)^(-1) A^T b`.
I have a system of linear convolutions: `Conv2D(X, w) = b`. What is the equivalent solution that minimizes the mean squared error?
The solution can either be pure mathematical or tensorflow code.

Is this what deconvolution does? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16542698/7080183) suggests it, but then I don't understand the connection to [this explanation of deconvolution](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/12110).

Comment: Since your system also is a system of linear equations, simply apply the result you quote.  There doesn't seem to be any question to answer (apart from the coding, which wouldn't be on topic here).

Comment: I am not sure how to write the inverse of a convolution, that is required for the solution to the linear system in matrix notation

Comment: The convolution is a linear transformation and may be replaced by a matrix multiplication, i.e. Ax=b, where A is the matrix representing the convolution.

Comment: But I don't kow how to express the matrix A in terms of w for that approach

Comment: @nielsrolf That has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798888/2-d-convolution-as-a-matrix-matrix-multiplication

Comment: You can write code to compute the matrix. Given any black-box linear function $f$ that takes any structure of numeric values $X$ and returns vectors $f(X),$ do the following. First, represent $X$ as an array $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n).$ Find a "base" value $X$ where you can apply $f$ to $X$ and to vectors of the form $X(i;\epsilon)=(x_1,\ldots, x_{i-1},x_i+\epsilon, x_{i+1},\ldots,x_n)$ for suitably small $\epsilon.$ Then, systematically compute the vectors $$A_i=\frac{f(X(i;\epsilon))-f(X)}{\epsilon},$$ $i=1,\ldots, n.$ These are the columns of the matrix $\mathbb A$ for which $f(X)=\mathbb{A}X.$